# Is it okay to have user email addresses and passwords stored in standard Mongo Collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, user-management

I am making an app that needs accounts, but I find all of the account management frameworks for Node.js to be too complicated. Would it be a bad idea to store user info in a regular collection? How could I do this to maximize security? I.E. encryption. What would you recommend as a strategy for this user management?

Answer (score 1):

No, never save passwords, hash and save the hash. The only safe solution is to never ever save passwords on the server.

The hash function should be similar to PBKDF2, a salted-hashed-iterated function that is a time-consuming one-way function.

Also two-factor authentication on the server is necessary.